# Display ordered data using django mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

I have the following following django statement:

```
pending_companies = PendingCompany.objects.order_by('submit_time').reverse()
```

Output:

```
petroshkin  Nov. 15, 2013, 2:27 p.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 2:26 p.m.
SEWORKS     Nov. 13, 2013, 11:17 a.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 11:06 a.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 11:07 a.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 11:09 a.m.
Copmew345re Nov. 12, 2013, 11:07 a.m.
```

The overall data should be reversed but for a repetitive company the data should not be reversed:

```
Petroshkin  Nov. 15, 2013, 2:27 p.m.
SEWORKS     Nov. 13, 2013, 11:17 a.m
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 11:06 a.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 11:07 a.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 11:09 a.m.
Copmew345   Nov. 13, 2013, 2:26 p.m.
Copmew345re Nov. 12, 2013, 11:07 a.m.
```

I tried working the following statement but it did not give me the result:

```
pending_companies.query.group_by = ['name']
```

Comment: How about `pending_companies = PendingCompany.objects.order_by('-submit_time', 'name').group_by('name')` ?

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'